# Did anyone has data duplication while doing Incremental import into hive?

Tags: sqoop

Anyone of you faced issue with data duplication while doing Incremental import into hive and how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the "search" feature of Stack Overflow to find similar problems. As @Theubald tries to explain, a typical issue with "incremental" stuff is that **by default** the current state is stored on a **local file** for the **current user**. And people don't read the Sqoop documentation, nor use Google, they just post a question on S.O. -- right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a primary key on the table,you will not get data duplication while incremental import

use unique key or define primary key on the table.

--check-column (primarykey/unique key) -->use this to avoid data duplication